# Can I change the color?

Tags: java, android, xml, colors, bitmap

I am using the following code to make a star button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/leftButton"

    android:onClick = "Star"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:Color="#FFFF00"   //I tried adding this, but no luck :(
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star" />
```

The button currently looks white:

[image]

**Is there anyway I can make it yellow?**

I know I can't have two background attributes, but is there anything I can do to change the color of this star? I want to keep the star as a background attribute, rather than a source attribute, because I want to be able to change the size of it.

Comment: I would really appreciate any help, as I have been trying to figure this out for over an hour now!

Comment: how do you decide when it has do by displayed the yellow version?

Comment: Do you want to change to color to yellow onclick? or just a static yellow icon? If static, why not replace the drawable icon by a yellow colored one?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Try this: android:tint="@color/yellow_tint", where yellow_tint being #FFFF00 in colors.xml, HTH.

Comment: you have to use your own image instead of android. And if you want to change color on click then you have to use two separate images for that one white, other yellow

Comment: @VivekMishra not in onclick. Just want a yellow star button...

Comment: @RuchirBaronia If that's the case, check my answer, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to yellow the star icon, then you can use `ColorFiler` for this. As follows:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star);
drawable.setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is  'PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP'

Comment: What does that mean? Thanks!

Comment: Please go through the link http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html which has good explanation of different porterduff modes.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. You can add different colorized images and change them at runtime, but much better way is to use a xml drawable. For icons with xml files take a look at https://materialdesignicons.com (there are much more sites like that outside)

In the xml file you can change the color directly

Answer (score 0):

Your **xml** file.

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/leftButton"
        android:tint="@color/yellow_tint"
        android:onClick = "Star"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star" />
```

**colors.xml**

```
<resources>

 <color name="yellow_tint">#FFFF00</color>

</resources>
```

Try it and let me know. Refer to this: [Working with Drawables](http://developer.android.com/training/material/drawables.html). I'm afraid android:color won't work in Drawables.

Answer (score 0):

**(background_star.xml) on drawable folder:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/star_yellow" <!-- image yellow -->
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/star_normal" /> <!-- image normal-->
</selector>
```

**on layout file:**

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="cancel alarm"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:background="@drawable/background_star" <!-- change this -->
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: Lucas appears to suggest that you add an additional asset for this.